# Dynamic outbound IP on Azure

Tags: azure

I have a REST API that is protected by the Cloudflare firewall, and a client of mine who uses my API started to have problems with using the API, because his IP that connects to my API has a bad reputation on HoneyProject.
He informed me that his system is hosted on Azure with a fixed IP, but the connections coming from him are always with two random IPs that are blocked.

Is there any way he can define which IPs to use?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-portal

Answer (score 0):

Assuming he is using a VM in Azure, there are 4 ways to set the outbound IP:

1. Assign a public IP to the VM
2. Put the VM behind a load balancer with a static IP assigned
3. Use [virtual network NAT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-overview)
4. Use an Azure Firewall

If it is not a VM we will need more details of what they are using.